# how to make lists from big list containing numbers as floats

Tags: python

here is a list (its a short one for example) this is from a survey and is stored in sqlite database as tuple which I converted into list

```
bmi=[ 38.09, 23.15, 41, 22.35, 18.6, 28.3 ]
```

expecting output
`bmi1 =  [23.15, 22.35,]`
     .
i want to seperate the numbers into different lists by their ranges example 20 to 25 one list, 25 to 30 another. etc.
how can i do that i tried "for loop" but it shows floats cannot be iteratable. 
basically how can i loop floating numbers and make new lists

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

bmis = [ 38.09, 23.15, 41, 22.35, 18.6, 28.3 ]

buckets = defaultdict(list)

def bucket_name(n):
    ''' Return the name of the bucket that should hold the given 'n' '''
    return 5 * int(n / 5)   # round down to the nearest multiple of 5

for bmi in bmis:
    buckets[bucket_name(bmi)].append(bmi)
```

That should build a dictionary whose keys are the starting points of the ranges (15,  20, 25, ...) and whose values are lists containing the numbers that belong in each range.  With the example input it will look like this:

```py
    {
        40: [41],
        25: [28.3],
        35: [38.09],
        20: [23.15, 22.35],
        15: [18.6]
    }
```

---

OP asked:

> can you explain a bit ...

I'm guessing the `defaultdict` is the part you haven't seen before.

An ordinary `dict` will throw an exception if you try to read an item that does not exist in the `dict`.  So if `buckets` was an ordinary `dict` if you were trying to place a value into the `20` bucket you might do this:

```py
    buckets[20].append(bmi)
```

to get the current `20` item, which it expects to be a list, and then it appends the new `bmi` to that list.  However, if the `buckets` `dict` did not already contain a `20` item then that line would fail and throw an exception.  To get the program to work with an ordinary `dict` you would have to add extra code to deal with the case where the bucket item you want to use does not already exist.  It's not a ton of extra code, but makes the program logic more complex.  It would look something like this:

```py
buckets = {}    # an empty ordinary dict

for bmi in bmis:
    bucket = bucket_name(bmi)
    if bucket not in buckets:
        buckets[bucket] = [ bmi ]    # a new list with one element
    else:
        buckets[bucket].append(bmi)
```

A `defaultdict` solves this problem.  If you try to read an item from a `defaultdict` but that item does not already exist, the `defaultdict` automatically creates the item, gives it a default value, and then returns that default value to your program.  So you don't have to have extra code to deal with creating an item if it doesn't already exist.

When you create a `defaultdict` dictionary you specify the name of a function that it will call to get the default value of an automatically-created item.  So this line:

```py
buckets = defaultdict(list)
```

creates a `defaultdict` that will create new entries automatically and set them to the value returned by calling the `list` function.  `list` is a standard built-in Python function that returns an empty list.  So the `buckets` variable is a dictionary that automatically creates new items whose initial value is an empty list.  That means that if we do:

```py
    buckets[20].append(bmi)
```

when a `buckets[20]` item does not already exist, it will be created automatically as a new empty list `[]` and then the `bmi` value will be appended to that list, producing a list with `bmi` as its only member.  With the `defaultdict` there is no extra logic to check whether the item exists before you use it (or no exception that needs to be caught and handled, if you wanted to deal with it that way).

The documentation for `defaultdict` is [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#defaultdict-objects).  It's a little terse, but the examples are helpful.

Comment: thank you it worked.if it is not too much to ask can you explain a bit . cause I have never seen this way before. and I cannot fully understand.

Comment: Great Explanation. Thanks!